# SOAP/HTTP using different folder mappings in ColdFusion

Tags: soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with a ColdFusion 11 server, which (among other things) publishes some web services accessed via both SOAP and HTTP. The server itself is Windows 2012, running IIS. Actual folder config is as follows:

[image: Folder config]

IIS has two websites configured, 'BOB' and 'BOB_Services'. Both have been configured with the CF Server Config tool so that CF handles .cfc, .cfm files. They share a common CFIDE config.

- BOB's root is I:/inetpub/BOB
- BOB_Services's root is I:/inetpub/BOB_Services

There is a folder mapping configured in CF Admin from '/' to 'I:/inetpub/BOB'. Don't ask me why, no one seems to know.

Normally there is a `services.cfc` file in `BOB_Services` **ONLY**. Yesterday we accidentally copied that same file into the `BOB` root folder, and all of our SOAP services using `BOB_Services\services.cfc` started throwing errors. Yet I can query the same webservice via HTTP (eg. using http://bob/services.cfc?method=function1&param1=0 ....etc) and get a valid result.

Comment: There is no question in this question - it is just a series of statements about what you did and what happened. Is there anything particular you were trying to get an answer for?

Comment: @MT0 - no, I was providing a 'question' so I could document this behaviour. I couldn't find anything on Google while we were bashing our heads against this one, so hopefully the next poor sap who runs into it has an easier time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reference answer in case anyone else comes across this strange behaviour.

It appears that when `BOB_Services/services.cfc` is called using HTTP GET, the folder mapping

`'/' -> 'I:/inetpub/BOB'`

is ignored and the actual file used to process the request is `I:/inetpub/BOB_Services/services.cfc`.

When a function in `BOB_Services/services.cfc` is called using a SOAP client, the folder mapping is invoked and the file used to process the request is `I:/inetpub/BOB/services.cfc`, **IF IT EXISTS**. If it does not exist, the file `I:/inetpub/BOB_Services/services.cfc` is used as expected.

This behaviour appears to be entirely repeatable - I can make a SOAP request, get one result, change the mapping, make another request and get the other result.